# Generating a compiler warning on bad static functions usage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, static-methods

I'm doing some maintenance on a VS C++ project, and I often see static member functions used as class methods.

For example:

```
class A {
public:
    static int func(int i);
};

...
A* a = new A();
a->func(3);
...
```

is there a way to generate a warning from the compiler so that I can clean up all the source code like this:

```
...
A::func(3);
...
```

Since I can get warnings for unused and declared variables, I was thinking that there should be something similar for these type of bad member usage, but with no luck: even if I set `/Wall` in compiler options I get no warning from the compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756459/warning-for-calling-static-methods-via-instance-object-in-c

Comment: why should there be a warning? It's perfectly good c++. You are wrong to "clean it up"

Comment: A fast method would be to search for all your static functions, rename them to something like `static int STATIC_func(int i);`, rebuild, you'll get compiler errors in lines such as `a->func(3);`, so then instead of fixing them to `a->STATIC_func(3);`, fix them to `A::STATIC_func(3);`. At the end, do a search for `STATIC_func` and change it to `func` again. Maybe your IDE supports refactoring, so you can do that last renaming automatically. Be sure however that you have a good reason to do that "fix". The code is perfectly correct.

Comment: @Hayt Nice find, but wrong compiler. Still relevant though.

Comment: @RichardHodges: since I get warnings like C4101 ("unreferenced local variable") if I declare `A a;` for example and I don't use it, then I'm thinking I should get the same if I write: `A a; a.func(1);` instead of `A::func(1);` There's a "waste" of variables in both cases.

Comment: @ABCplus so what happens when the class maintainer decides that this should no longer be a static function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler need not give any warning, because for `static` member method `func()`, both of below invocations are valid:

```
a->func(3);  // calling as of it's a non-static member method
A::func(3);  // calling as a proper `static` member method
```

However, you are right in identifying that the `A::func(3)` is more informative for the reader which explicitly suggests that `func()` is a `static` member.

> "is there a way to generate a warning from the compiler ... ?"

Unfortunately there is no way to detect a correct syntax which is less preferred.
But you can perform **negative compilation**:

```
private: static int func(int i);  // make `func()` inaccessible outside `class A`
```

Compile the code by making a given `static` method `private`. This will generate errors at whichever prohibited places the `func()` is invoked. Now you may correct it and again remove the `private:` specifier.
This is bit tedious, yet sure shot way.

You may also use the "call hierarchy" feature in IDEs like "Eclipse-CDT", but chances are there that `template`s or some tricky function calls are missed.

Comment: @RichardHodges, what if the OP is assigned with "code clean up" task :-). IMO, changing the calling convention from "non static way" to "static way" is actually quite productive. When another coder looks at the code, he/she can identify immediately that the method is `static` or not without looking at its definition. Calling a `static` method like a non-static method is quite distracting.