# Having named constructors while avoiding their use as a method?

Tags: c++, syntax, c++20, static-methods, named-constructor

I *really* like the syntax of "named constructors," which I understand to be static methods that return the object hosting them?  (I apologize if "named constructors" isn't the right term for this.)  But I've accidentally called them as a member way too many times...  I'm wondering if there's a way to possibly keep this syntax, while helping myself avoid this mistake?

```
class TextureDef {
public:
    TextureDef(){} // default value of 1x1x1, 2D, r8, etc
    static TextureDef as1D(uint32 xSize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 mipmapCount = 1);
    static TextureDef as2D(uint32 xSize, uint32 ySize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 mipmapCount = 1);
    static TextureDef as3D(uint32 xSize, uint32 ySize, uint32 zSize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 mipmapCount = 1);
    static TextureDef as1Darray(uint32 xSize, uint32 arrayCount, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 mipmapCount = 1);     
    static TextureDef as2Darray(uint32 xSize, uint32 ySize, uint32 arrayCount, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8,uint8 mipmapCount = 1);        
    static TextureDef asBuffer(uint32 xSize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8);    
    static TextureDef asRect(uint32 xSize, uint32 ySize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8);        
    static TextureDef asCubemap(uint32 xySize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 mipmapCount = 1);       
    static TextureDef asCubemapArray(uint32 xySize, uint32 arrayCount, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 mipmapCount = 1);
    static TextureDef as2DMS(uint32 xSize, uint32 ySize, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 samples = 4);     
    static TextureDef as2DMSarray(uint32 xSize, uint32 ySize, uint32 arrayCount, TextureFormat::Type format = TextureFormat::rgba8, uint8 samples = 4); 

    ...
};

void usageExample(Canvas & canvas) {

    // this syntax feels really nice, 'cause I'm a loser who leans auto-complete
    canvas.allocTexture(TextureDef::as2D(100, 100));

    // BUT... I sometimes burn myself by accident...
    TextureDef def;
    def.as2D(100, 100);  // `def` is unaffected
    canvas.allocTexture(def); 
}
```

I've adopted a consistent naming convention for these kind of methods. `static Point Point::asPolar(...);` where `as` is always the first word.  "As" if that would help.

I've also thought of making the default constructor be private?  If that is the best way, I'm not sure though...

(As rationale for why I'm stubborn about a syntax that's so prone to pain, it's because... I often forget my own free-functions, and naming anything in the global namespace is a lot of pressure.  Making a namespace for them feels weird too because I would want to name this namespace the same as the class?  Having them in the class's namespace helps me out a lot.)

Comment: In C++17 and later, you can mark the return value with [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) so that calls like `def.as2D(...)` will fail to compile if you don't use the return value for anything.

Comment: You can use `[[nodiscard]]` to prevent discarding. It's not really a constructor but a creator method, a distant ancestor of [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: You could perhaps wrap them in an internal class called `Construct`, so you then must do `TextureDef::Construct::as2D(100, 100);`... But I think the issue is you have weird naming. The operation `someTexture.as2D()` implies some sort of conversion of an existing object, not a context-free construction. Why not rename them as `create2D()` and make it more clear?

Comment: @paddy - that is much more clear, I'll use create instead then!  And also, I'll try [[nodiscard]] too swift, I saw a mention of it, but was disappointed that it only results in a pretty soft compiler warning

Comment: @AnneQuinn, if you're open to another suggestion, Python's datetime library uses `fromXXX`, and I like the way that looks - `TextureDef::from2D(...)`

Comment: @Ben - that's pretty good too, I mostly went with 'as' because it's short and can by typed with only my left hand... this is a very dumb reason I realize, but I like create since it's a left-hand only word too (with qwerty anyway)

Comment: As others mentioned, naming conventions is about as good as it gets. `make` is also a popular prefix for named constructors, both static members or free functions.

Comment: You could use functors, I suppose, if you don't mind the extra syntax. It seems a bit code-smelly. Still, [here's a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9shMbfbca) demonstrating the impossibility of invoking that on an object because it's a type.

Comment: I thought of defining a deleted non-static function to make calls from inside the class ambiguous, while calls from outside with no target object would find only the static function.  But C++ has some unfortunate overload resolution rules that prevent this.

Comment: It's a factory pattern, so why not just create a `TextureDefFactory` holding these functions?

Comment: It seems there are no available [warning-for-calling-static-methods-via-instance-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756459/warning-for-calling-static-methods-via-instance-object-in-c), so checking that the result is used (with `[[nodiscard]]`) seems an good alternative.